# MS SQL table --> MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a table (Accounts.sql) back-upped from Microsoft SQL (MsSQL). Now I would like to use them in my MySQL.

I tried to import it but it didn't work.

Q: Is there any way i can use this back-upped table in my MYSQL?

Here is the sample of another table opened in a text editor (Curriculum Details.sql)

```
USE [DHVCAT]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ES_CurriculumDetails]    Script Date: 12/03/2014 14:42:41 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ES_CurriculumDetails](
    [IndexID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CurriculumID] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ES_CurriculumDetails_CurriculumID]  DEFAULT (0),
    [YearTermID] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ES_CurriculumDetails_YearTermID]  DEFAULT (0),
    [SubjectID] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ES_CurriculumDetails_SubjectID]  DEFAULT (0),
    [YearStandingID] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__ES_Curric__YearS__18FA9ADD]  DEFAULT (0),
    [EquivalentSubjectID] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ES_CurriculumDetails_EquivalentSubjectID]  DEFAULT (0),
    [SortOrder] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__ES_Curric__SortO__39E5C205]  DEFAULT (0),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CurriculumDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IndexID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Curriculum code relate to ES_Curriculums' ,@level0type=N'SCHEMA', @level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE', @level1name=N'ES_CurriculumDetails', @level2type=N'COLUMN', @level2name=N'CurriculumID'

GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'SubjectID relate to ES_Subject' ,@level0type=N'SCHEMA', @level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE', @level1name=N'ES_CurriculumDetails', @level2type=N'COLUMN', @level2name=N'SubjectID'
```

Comment: How did you backup the table? When you say backup, do you mean data or just the structure?

Comment: How big is the backup file? Can you try open it in a text editor?

Comment: I've added the codes in my question above. sorry but i do not know the difference between data & structure back up.

Answer (score 0):

You've scripted the table, which doesn't include the data for the table. The create table (and other) syntax is different for mysql than it is for sql server. You'll be able to use the file you have as a starting point, but you'll have to edit it with the mysql equivalent.

Try googling "sql server create table mysql equivalent"

Hope that helps